# PHP: Strip Wrapping Paragraph Tags

Tags: php, htmlpurifier, substr, strip-tags

I need to write a PHP function which removes opening and closing paragraph tags from a string, but only if they are at the very beginning/end.  So the strings:

```
"Simple Test"
"<p>Here</p>"
"<p>Test <p>Nested</p> Outside </p>"
```

Would Output:

```
"Simple Test"
"Here"
"Test <p>Nested</p> Outside"
```

Can HTMLPurifier do this or should I use substr?  My first attempt was:

```
if(strpos($str,'<p>') === 0  && strcmp(substr($str,-1,4),'</p>'))
$str = substr($str,3,strlen($str)-4);
```

Comment: it's exactly what regexps were made for. However substring solution is OK too. Don't forget various invisible characters like spaces tabs and line endings

Comment: Do you trust where the input is coming from? Will it always be simply `<p></p>`, or could it be things like `<P style=""></P>`?

Comment: It's coming from a CK Editor, so non-malicious code is predictable and doesn't allow any styles.  In this case, I'm removing these to avoid redundancy not security.

HTMLPurifier is protecting against XSS to handle that side of things.

Comment: no its not. @col. shrapnel. only if you recard it as strings. if you regard it as markup, html, a structured document, ... then some xpath/domdocument parsing is the way to go.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a regex solution:

```
$str = preg_replace('!^<p>(.*?)</p>$!i', '$1', $str);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this fail on nested <p>-Tags? Try <p class="outer">does<p class="inner>this</p>work?</p>.

Comment: no, why should it? be aware of the beginning ^ and ending $ indicator

Comment: The regex will only match `<p>` at the start of the string because the [`^` anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) is there. So it won't do anything to nested `<p>` tags. It doesn't handle the tag having any attributes, because the question didn't seem to require it.

Comment: Exactly. It will leave the part <p class="inner">this</p> unchanged, requiring iterative application of the regexp to replace all occurrences.

Comment: He *wants* the regex to leave nested `<p>` tags as they are - see the third test case string in the question. :S

Comment: OK, then your regex is perfect, then. I withdraw my criticism :)

Answer (score 2):

A Regular Expression like

```
</??p(?:\s+\w*)>
```

will match your <p\ >, </p> and <p somestuff> - use that regexp and replace matches with emtpy string or whatever you like.

HTH

PS: use the "ignore case" flag, just in case.

Edit: made the group a non-capturing one.

Answer (score 2):

this is a regex way.

its fine if the only requirement is to strip the exact wrapping strings `<p>` and `</p>`

if you need a generic solution which is robust for html you should use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).
(for example if you want to acceppt classes, ids and variaous attributes in your wrapping paragraph tags.)
but be aware that loading a domdocument will normalize your html.

```
<?
$str = array(
"Simple Test",
"<p>Here</p>",
"<p>Test <p>Nested</p> Outside </p>"
);

foreach($str as $st) {
  echo $st." ---> ";
  if(preg_match('#<p>(.+)</p>#',$st,$match) === 1) { // 1 if matched, 0 if not matched
    $st = $match[1]; // if matched, replace our string by the match
  }
  echo $st."\n";
}
```

this will generate this output:

```
Simple Test ---> Simple Test
<p>Here</p> ---> Here
<p>Test <p>Nested</p> Outside </p> ---> Test <p>Nested</p> Outside
```

you could easily make thie a one liner. for example with preg_replace and regex backreferences you could replace the string which the match... but i hope in this form its more understandable to you.

Comment: Thank you, this is much easier to follow than the one line solutions.

Answer (score -1):

The not so fancy pattern, but works `$inf = preg_replace('/<[\/]*?p.*?>/', '', $info);`

Comment: it replaces all <P> tags, not only first and last